# For X a Y, something is true

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, scientific-language

Often in mathematical writing I read (and write) constructions such as

> For G a finite group, the character algebra is defined as ...

> For X and Y sets, a function from X to Y is ...

The general structure here is

> For NAME a TYPE, SOMETHING is true

i.e. we give something of a certain type a name, and then state some property or definition.

I'm not a native speaker, so I'm wondering if these constructions are correct in standard English, or if it is simply a product of a lot of non-native speakers contributing to science, and adding their own language's quirks into their writing.

My questions: Does it have a name? Is it formally/grammatically correct?

Comment: I think you'll find that specialized fields develop their own linguistical shorthand which rarely, is common use in the language as a whole.

Comment: If G is a finite group, I have often seen it written *For G, a finite group, the...*. It is necessary to set off the *appositive* in commas. The appositive is explaining and restricting what G is.

Answer (score 1):

The structure can be explained:

- *For G a finite group, the character algebra is defined as ...*

is essentially a variant of

- *For any finite group G, the character algebra is defined as ...*

and can be considered a deleted form of

- *For **the situation where** G **is** a finite group, the character algebra is defined as ...*

................   Similarly,

*For **the situation where** X and Y **are [suitable]** sets, a function from X to Y is ...*

Mathspeak is preferred to the perhaps rather unprofessional-sounding spelled-out versions.

The 'suitable' is pragmatic, to pre-empt the arranging of silly, arbitrary (though 'legitimate' from other considerations) mappings. People's shoe sizes mapping to their favourite pets.